# plotting ISS with matplotlibtoolkit

Tags: matplotlib

I wont plot the position of the ISS frequently. Found some code on the internet. Changed it for python 3.5.1.
When it runs in a while loop it shows only a white screen.
Running it without the while loop and delete the last two lines of code it shows the ISS on the world map!

What to changed to get it working. 
Try to run it on a Macbook.

```
""" plot the ISS and update every 60 seconds"""
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import time
import urllib.request
import json


def getiss():
""" call opennotify api"""
print('Get ISS data')
r=urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json',timeout=4)
mydata = json.loads(r.read().decode(r.info().get_param('charset') or 'utf-8'))
return(mydata)

while True:
    iss = getiss()
    lat = iss['iss_position']['latitude']
    lon = iss['iss_position']['longitude']

    # miller projection
    map = Basemap(projection='mill',lon_0=0)
    # plot coastlines, draw label meridians and parallels.
    map.drawcoastlines()
    map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30),labels=[1,0,0,0])
    map.drawmeridians(np.arange(map.lonmin,map.lonmax+30,60),labels=[0,0,0,1])
    # fill continents 'coral' (with zorder=0), color wet areas 'aqua'
    map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
    map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
    # shade the night areas, with alpha transparency so the 
    # map shows through. Use current time in UTC.
    date = datetime.now()
    CS=map.nightshade(date)
    plt.title('ISS Location For for %s Lat: %.2f Long: %.2f' % (date.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"),lat,lon))

    x,y = map(lon, lat)
    map.plot(x, y, 'bo', markersize=12)
    plt.ion()
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(60) 
    plt.clf()
```